# Laravel and results of stored MySQL Procedures

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, frameworks

I'm dealing with some really old code I'm trying to get running on Laravel. The database is complicated and full of unnecessarily long stored procedures that I don't have the budget to rewrite.

For the most part, these work well, as I can access singular results like
    $myID = $result[0]->id

I'm hoping this is something more than a gap in my PHP knowledge...

```
$result = DB::select(DB::raw("Call MyOldStoredProcedure()"));
print_r($result);
```

This gives me:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [MIN(user_responses.sectionid)] => 2 ) )
```

Which I unsurprisingly can't access as

```
$number = $result[0]["MIN(user_responses.sectionid)"]; //or...
$number = $result[0]->...
```

What can I do to retrieve this singular result from this weird associative array/object? I'm about to give up and parse the array string, but I know there's a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option is to use curly braces in order to be able to quote the special characters:

```
$number = $result[0]->{'MIN(user_responses.sectionid)'};
```

Another option is to set a variable to the name of the property, and then access the property using the variable:

```
$property = 'MIN(user_responses.sectionid)';
$number = $result[0]->$property;
```

Additionally, you could also convert the object to an array, and access the property like you originally attempted.

```
$array = (array)$result[0];
$number = $array['MIN(user_responses.sectionid)'];

// or, if you're on PHP 7+
$number = ((array)$result[0])['MIN(user_responses.sectionid)'];
```

Comment: Nailed it. Didn't know curly braces were a thing when accessing an object. Time to re-read some docs! Thank you.